# How can I change the directory a relative path points to in apache?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, relative-path

I have a website running on an apache2 server and serving out of a user directory. The URL looks like this: `http://example.com/~user1`

This serves up files on my server located at `/home/user1`. The problem that I am facing is that a lot of the asset URLs throughout the site are put into the HTML as relative paths like this: `<img src="/images/example.png" alt="" />`

This is attempting to load the image from `http://example.com/images/example.png`, but I actually want it to serve from `http://example.com/~user1/images/example.png`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> /images/example.png
> ```

This is a *root-relative*, not a *relative* URL-path.

> This is attempting to load the image from `http://example.com/images/example.png`, but I actually want it to serve from `http://example.com/~user1/images/example.png`.

This is a client-side/browser URL resolution issue. There are no "switches" on the server that can be applied to change this behaviour, without changing the actual URLs.

This is an inherent problem with using [Apache per-user web directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html).

Your options are:

1. Don't use Apache per-user web directories. ie. Remove `/~<user1>/` from the URL.

Or,

2. Use *relative* URL-paths to your assets. eg. `images/example.png` (no slash prefix). So the *browser* correctly resolves this as `/~user1/images/example.png` instead (when accessed from the document root at least). But this creates additional problems if you are rewriting the URL of your pages at different path depths or using common templates in your pages etc.